# Win7/Server2008: Automatic differences SSD/HDD installation

Tags: windows, ssd, trim, alignment

It is said that a new installed Win7/2008 has "some" settings different
if it was installed on a SSD than they would be on a HDD.

Do someone have a reliable statement on what exactly is different?

I know many guides on the net describing what one should do with a SSD to optimize it,
that´s not what i´m asking for. I´m asking only for the automatic settings
depending on the drive type at intall time.

The reason for my question is that i want to move SSD content to a HDD
(yes, not vice-versa).
If Win7 is configured to send TRIM to the device,
will it be a problem to the HDD (or will Windows recognize the change itself)?
Is the special alignmnt a problem for a HDD?

Comment: "It is said that a new installed Win7/2008 has "some" settings different if it was installed on a SSD than they would be on a HDD" - Maybe you could provide us a link where you read this?

Comment: Well, i read it on multiple sites, but for example, the TRIM-stuff is clearly a difference. There are commands to manually enable/disable it (described for example here: http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=86403); and when installing, the initial setting depends on the disk type (i checked that)